# Link to URL based on form input upon clicking submit

Tags: javascript, python, html

My goal is to have a user enter a date to retrieve forecast data from the selected date.  My URL's are of the form wwww.mywebsite.com/forecasts/region/{{date}} (I'm using Pyramid's URL dispatch).  I want the user to be able to enter a date in the format YYYYMMDDHH and upon clicking submit the user is taken to that date's url.  Is there a way to do this in HTML?  Or would Javascript, or server-side python be a better option?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily with python on server side like this:

```
@view_config(route_name='foo')
def foo(request):
    #get date like something like this:
    if ('date' in request.params.keys()):
        userInputDate = request.params.get('date')

    #redirect the user to date specific view
    return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('bar', date = userInputDate)

@view_config(route_name='bar', renderer='bar.mak')
def bar(request):
   #get that usergiven date
   date = request.matchdict['date']
   #do stuff
```

Route definition for the bar:

```
config.add_route('bar','/bar/{date:\d+}')
```

This creates urls with changing values, like dates. More information about this here: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/narr/urldispatch.html